# Which versions of Perl are you using?

Tags: perl, perl5.8

According to the Perl source code page on CPAN, 5.8.9 is now 14 days old, and will be the last 5.8 release. 5.10.0 is over a year old and presumably ready for use in Production.

Leaving aside discussion of Perl 6 for now, can I ask what versions of Perl folks are testing, rolling out and using in production? We have currently standardized on 5.8.8 on our Ubuntu (workstation) and Solaris (production) platforms, and I'm wondering about the pros and cons of making small step to 5.8.9 or a larger one to 5.10.0.

Comment: Please make the title of this question more descriptive.

Comment: Are you the talexb user on Perlmonks who orginally wrote this question a couple of days ago? http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=733290

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Perl Survey, performed over a year ago now predating 5.10, as their **minimum** version of Perl people are using...

```
4.x     3%
5.0.x   3%
5.4.x   2%
5.5.x   6%
5.6.x   17%
5.8.x   66%
```

and the **maximum** is...

```
5.6.x   3%
5.8.x   88%
5.9.x   5%
```

5.6.1 and 5.8.8 are most popular within their major group.  The missing percentages are miscellaneous versions.

Since the survey didn't define what "using" means, ie. if you're actually running production code on it or if you just test your software against it for backwards compatibility, or you just have it around for kicks, the minimum can be taken with a grain of salt.

This data, and the general lack of feedback from users, lead me to drop support for 5.5.x from the module installation toolchain modules I maintain (MakeMaker and Test::More) effectively [end-of-lifing 5.5.x](http://perlbuzz.com/2007/11/one-man-kills-perl-55-and-more-power-to-him.html).  5.6 has had a stay of execution, but is still on death row.

I personally only recently switched from 5.8.8 to 5.10.0.  I know of places still using 5.6.1 in legacy apps, but they've moved to 5.8.8 for as much as possible and all new dev.  I don't know of anyone still using 5.5 in production.  For backwards compatibility I test against 5.6.2, 5.8.8 and 5.10.0.  The numbers say I should be testing 5.6.1 instead of 5.6.2 but there's only so far I can be arsed by folks who won't even upgrade to the latest bugfix release in their line.

Answer (score 4):

I use Perl 5.10.0 in development and 5.8.8 in production and code is tested for compatibility. But I haven't seen so many internal Perl bugs than in Perl version 5.10.0 It's really terrible. I have reported three easily reproducible assert violations and core dumping ones and still cope with some strange hard to reproduce bugs which causes core dumps, memory leaks and so.

Comment: The .0 releases should never be used unless you're the sort that likes pain and suffering and bug reporting. :)

Comment: 5.10.0 was an extremely solid release, especially compared to 5.8.0 (or 5.8.1), so I wonder what's going on here.  Did you build Perl yourself or is this some pre-packaged version?

Comment: Well, 5.10.0 was solid except when it wasn't, like broken and untested smart matching.

Comment: We have >150kSLOC project and there we triggered above mentioned regressions. It doesn't contain new features. So those issues fixed months ago.

Answer (score 4):

Perl 5.8.8 is (and will be until at least 5.10.1) our production environment. The performance regressions in 5.10.0 (regarding @_ assignment in sub's for example) make it impossible for us in production.

But we run our test suites with both 5.8.8 and 5.10.0 to prepare our move to 5.10.x in the future. I'm trying to have a system that will compile the bleadperl and run our test suites with that also...

Answer (score 2):

Primary development 5.10, QA and production 5.8.8 .

Answer (score 1):

We're using v5.6.1 in our production server. I guess we're old school. :P

Unless there's a specific features that you need, I think just upgrading might require plenty of testing on all related components.

So that only answers your first question. For the second one, you might want to research on what's the new features in the newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I use primarily Perl 5.10.0.  I test backwards compatibility on 5.6.1 and 5.8.8.  I do still have a Perl 5.5.3 which I occasionally use.  (I still have the source for 5.4.4 - or 5.004_04 as it was then termed; it is not currently built and I can think of few reasons why I'd need to do so.)

Thanks for the information about 5.8.9.  I'll have to get that.

Answer (score 1):

I just started using 5.10.0 a few weeks ago, but I keep testing my modules on 5.8. When I upload something on CPAN I will put an effort in making it 5.6 compatible if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might also like my answer to [How do *YOU* manage Perl modules on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398221/how-do-you-manage-perl-modules-on-linux#398397). I install several versions of Perl and test against many of them.

Answer (score 1):

5.8.8 on FreeBSD for production and development. We're preparing to roll out a VM/jail to test 5.10 in (to verify compatibility for the future).

Answer (score 1):

I use `Perl 5.10`, mainly because I can hardly wait until `Perl6` implementations, are more complete

Comment: Actually, now I am using `5.10.1` . I am also testing code on `5.11.0` .