# How can I upgrade my perl version in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, perl

I don't want to install multiple instances of perl.

How can I upgrade my Perl to latest version or delete existing Perl installation and install a new version of Perl in Ubuntu 14.04.
After new installation, will it conflict with older installation files.

Comment: It is a bad idea to update your 'system' perl, separately, as you may have things depending on it. Far better to do a source build and install in /usr/local/bin

Comment: @Sobrique can you please suggest how to do that

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
wget http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.22.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz perl-5.22.1.tar.gz
cd perl-5.22.1 && ./Configure -Duseithreads -des && make && make test && make install
/usr/local/bin/cpan -u
```

This puts a source build of `perl` in `/usr/local/bin`

Then check your path has /usr/local/bin in it, and if you want typing `perl` to run your new perl, ensure it's in front of `/usr/bin` (this is a fairly common scenario, but I can't say for sure if that applies.

Whilst you say you don't want to install multiple perl versions - this is a bad idea.

`perl` is distributed as part of your operating system. Packages depend upon it, and the particular version. You cannot tell what you might break by altering versions - not least because the way perl handles certain things *does* change between versions (like hashes).

Messing around with `/usr/bin/perl` is a road to some future pain (not least - it makes an 'update' of your OS annoyingly difficult, because you can no longer use the package manager without a bit of hackery)

If you REALLY REALLY want to do that you can set `-Dprefix=` in your `Configure` options. But as a sysadmin of 15 years experience, I can tell you - no good will come of it, you will break your OS in a variety of minor, but cumulatively really annoying ways. (And maybe some bigger ways)

Comment: in addition to Sobrique's answer, anyone can simply go to http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/ and just do ctrl+f and search which version you're looking for then download/wget it yourself

Comment: consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289564/how-should-i-install-more-than-one-version-of-perl