# What's the best way to turn CPAN modules into Debian packages?

Tags: perl, debian

Whenever I work on a system of any flavor that has a particular way of handling package management, I try to stick with that standard for managing my Perl modules.  "When in Rome, etc."

For example, on a Win32 system using ActivePerl, I use PPM for everything and use the great [PPM::Make](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/dist/PPM-Make).  On a RedHat system I prefer to use RPMs.

Now I am working on a Debian system, and find myself in need of a way to turn an arbitrary CPAN or CPAN style distribution into a deb.

Google shows options like dh-make-perl, CPANPLUS::Dist::Deb and CPAN::Packager::Builder::Deb.

Does anyone with experience with these different tools have any recommendations as to what to use or avoid?

What's the best way to handle building deb files from standard CPAN modules?

### Update:

I found [an article by Hans Dieter Piercy](http://www.opensourcery.com/blog/hans-dieter-pearcey/packaging-cpan-modules-debian) on this subject - he suggests, for his own needs, CPANPLUS tools.  Under some circumstances he recommends dh-make-perl.  Jeremiah Foster (who wrote the article brian d foy points to) responds to HDP and makes a case for dh-make-perl.

There's also [a post on idimmu.net](http://www.idimmu.net/2008/02/01/Turning-CPAN-modules-in-to-deb-with-dh-perl-make) that describes using dh-make-perl.

ATM, I'm leaning toward dh-make-perl, since that has been thrice recommended (brian d foy as proxy for Jeremy Foster, the idimmu.net author and hillu) vs once for CPANPLUS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`dh-make-perl`](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dh-make-perl&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) does a good job in taking care of the repetitive and heavy lifting and guessing information from the sources. It has worked correctly for almost all of the CPAN modules that I have packaged up as Debian packages (official or for in-house use only).

That said, the resulting package should only be considered as a starting point for a proper Debian packages. `dh-make-perl` puts warning notes into the automatically generated such as `debian/control` (i.e. description of the package and dependencies) and `debian/copyright` (licensing information).

In response to Manni, I believe that it is a **great** idea to work **with** the tools that the OS or distribution provides for package management, not against them. In the case of Debian, this means putting stuff into `.deb` packages and installing those. Perl's build tools and CPAN do a great job of providing a cross-platform build environment and for distribution of the source code, but compared to package management tools in modern Linux distributions, they perform suboptimally, simply because extra manual intervention is often required that is less easily automated across multiple machines than rolling up a package.

(For one-off and test installations, installing into `/usr/local/` and using [`stow(8)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) as a poor man's package manager may be okay.)

Even if you are just building the packages for your own use, consider contacting the Debian Perl Group and have someone sponsor an upload to Debian if you feel that the module in question is of use for other people.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you ask the Debian Perl Maintainers group, rather than here on SO.  Just mail the address shown as maintainer on any odd package:
`Debian Perl Group <pkg-perl-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>`

Back in the day, I added a few modules to Debian, and just 'did it by hand'. I still maintain some. That isn't hard either.  but the group now maintains way more package, and has tools.

Answer (score 3):

Jeremiah Foster published an article about turning Perl distros into Debian packages in the Spring 2009 issue of [The Perl Review](http://www.theperlreview.com).

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good step by step here as well. (also with links to other good resources and some decent comments. [it is dated 2005, but still mostly relavent and many comments much more recent])

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/78

here is the debian perl policy (also linked to in article)
http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/perl-policy/

Answer (score 1):

You won't like this, but I really think that you should **not** do this at all. The various Perl Debian packages aren't for developers that need certain Perl modules on their machines. They were built because other applications need them and users want or might want those applications.

Please take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398221/how-do-you-manage-perl-modules-on-linux) before doing something that you probably should not be doing.

Comment: I don't think that your advice is generally useful. There are reasons for going either way. Hey, some people insist on using their own Perl build for regular development work which probably doesn't make sense to 98% of those who use a distribution with well-maintained Perl packages.

Comment: While I agree that an application should take responsibility for its own dependencies, the question is not illegitimate and deserves a real answer.