# How can I avoid sudo-ing when installing Perl modules with 'cpan'?

Tags: perl, cpan, sudo

I have installed Perl from source into /usr/local, and adjusted my path accordingly, following [brian d foy's suggestion here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992720/perl-strategy-for-a-new-snow-leopard-user)

I'm sure I'm missing something, but, now I'm trying to install stuff with the 'cpan' command and it's failing because it can't write to /usr/local. I have to use sudo, which feels wrong to me. Should CPAN stuff go to another location? Is it normal to have to use sudo?

Answer (score 11):

If it really bothers you to use `sudo`, you can use [`local::lib`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib) and install modules in your home directory - where you don't need super-user privileges.

That said, it shouldn't bother you to use `sudo`. There's nothing necessarily wrong with it. As Gbacon says, you need it if you want to install in `/usr/local` because `/usr/local` is shared by *all* users on the system (and so its permissions reflect that):

```
    telemachus ~ $ ls -ld /usr/local/
    drwxr-xr-x 17 root wheel 578 Jan  8 20:00 /usr/local/
```

Comment: The problem with local::lib is maintaining distinct perls at the same time. If you want to isolate the installations completely as I suggest, you don't want to install the modules for the different perls in the same directory.

Answer (score 9):

The `/usr/local` tree is protected. It's perfectly normal to use `sudo` to install software there.

Installing to a separate library location is a frequently-asked question. See ["How do I keep my own module/library directory?"](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_keep_my_own) in section 8.

Key excerpt:

> You can set this in your `CPAN.pm` configuration so modules automatically install in your private library directory when you use the `CPAN.pm` shell:
>
> ```
> % cpan  
> cpan> o conf makepl_arg INSTALL_BASE=/mydir/perl  
> cpan> o conf commit
> ```
>
> For `Build.PL`-based distributions, use the --install_base option:
>
> ```
> perl Build.PL --install_base /mydir/perl
> ```
>
> You can configure `CPAN.pm` to automatically use this option too:
>
> ```
> % cpan  
> cpan> o conf mbuild_arg "--install_base /mydir/perl"  
> cpan> o conf commit
> ```

Comment: I think he's already doing this. The advice in the FAQ is insufficient for this. There's a  mbuild_install_build_command and a make_install_make_command option where you can set sudo as a command to use in the install step.

Answer (score 9):

The */usr/local* directory shouldn't be writeable by a normal user, but the Unix setup has many features to handle this.

In my advice, I suggested setting up */usr/local/perls*. You can give that directory whatever permissions you like. Don't apply any permissions to more directories than you need.

I suggest setting up a `perl` group, adding yourself to that group, and making the Perl library directories group writeable. Once setup, you don't have to sudo because you have group permissions.

Beyond that, you can adjust your CPAN.pm configuration to use `sudo` during the install phases. Check out the `make_install_make_command` and `mbuild_install_build_command` commands in the documentation. Just search for "sudo", and you'll find them.

Good luck, :)

Answer (score 7):

In your CPAN shell, configure it to run the `make` and `build` steps under sudo:

```
o conf make_install_make_command 'sudo make'
o conf mbuild_install_build_command 'sudo ./Build'
o conf commit
quit
```

(I found these [here](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.qa/2007/10/msg9443.html) -- I'm no CPAN guru.)