# W3C Validator on Mac OS X sending this error: Can't locate Config/General.pm

Tags: macos, perl, w3c, w3c-validation

I installed W3C Validator on my Mac OS X Yosemite. I followed these instructions: https://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html

Here is the command I tried:

> /usr/local/validator/cgi-bin/check uri=http://www.w3.org

I am getting this error:

```
<h1>Software error:</h1>
<pre>Can't locate Config/General.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Config::General module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18) at /usr/local/validator/cgi-bin/check line 47.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/validator/cgi-bin/check line 47.
</pre>
<p>
For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message 
and the time and date of the error.

</p>
[Thu Jun 25 01:04:18 2015] check: Can't locate Config/General.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Config::General module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18) at /usr/local/validator/cgi-bin/check line 47.
[Thu Jun 25 01:04:18 2015] check: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/validator/cgi-bin/check line 47.
```

check line 47:

```
use Config::General 2.32 qw();    # Need 2.32 for <msg 0>, rt.cpan.org#17852
```

I did a search on my computer for:

> sudo find / -name General.pm

I got this this result:

```
/Applications/Validator-SAC.app/Contents/Resources/validator/lib/perl5.10/Config/General.pm
/Applications/Validator-SAC.app/Contents/Resources/validator/lib/perl5.10.0/Config/General.pm
/Applications/Validator-SAC.app/Contents/Resources/validator/lib/perl5.12/Config/General.pm
/Applications/Validator-SAC.app/Contents/Resources/validator/lib/perl5.18/Config/General.pm
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/Config/Any/General.pm
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/Config/Any/General.pm
/Users/jeannicolas/.cpan/build/Config-General-2.58-ICngmR/blib/lib/Config/General.pm
/Users/jeannicolas/.cpan/build/Config-General-2.58-ICngmR/General.pm
/Users/jeannicolas/.cpan/build/Config-General-2.58-umQC4D/blib/lib/Config/General.pm
/Users/jeannicolas/.cpan/build/Config-General-2.58-umQC4D/General.pm
/Users/jeannicolas/perl5/lib/perl5/Config/General.pm
/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/autoconf/Autom4te/General.pm
/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.14/share/automake-1.14/Automake/General.pm
```

More details about my setup for perl:

```
$  which perl
```

> /usr/bin/perl

```
$  perl --version
```

> This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for
>   darwin-thread-multi-2level (with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for
>   more detail)
>
> Copyright 1987-2013, Larry Wall
>
> Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License
>   or the GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5
>   source kit.
>
> Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found
>   on this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access
>   to the Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl
>   Home Page.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have two versions of Perl installed, 5.10 and 5.18. I can see 5.18 is running from command line, but do you know which version the web server is running? Looks like Config::General installed ok for 5.10, but for 5.18 it's in an odd place:  /Users/jeannicolas/perl5/lib/perl5/Config/General.pm . Is your @INC array set up to include this in the path for included library modules?

Comment: I have no experience with Perl... I have no idea if my @INC array is setup to include this in the path for included library modules.

Comment: Don't know how you installed the extra librareies, but from this "/Users/jeannicolas/perl5/lib/perl5/Config/General.pm" looks like it hasn't gone to the normal place such as /System/Library/Perl/Extras/ May not be possible, but if you could wipe and reinstall perl and all the modules, it should work a lot better and you don't have to worry about @INC and $PERL5LIB

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and got past it by simply adding `sudo` when invoking `cpan` — not just for `Config::General`, but for all the dependencies:

```
sudo cpan install Bundle::W3C::Validator
```

Having done that, the w3c validator now works fine for me.

I’m not knowledgeable enough to be confident whether this is a good approach.  In other contexts, one’s often warned against installing things with `sudo`.  Various people (e.g. [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031956/how-can-i-avoid-sudo-ing-when-installing-perl-modules-with-cpan)) suggest that it’s OK to use `sudo` for `cpan` in general; however, they don’t discuss the Mac OS X context specifically.  [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89271/how-to-install-modules-from-cpan-without-sudo) gives an alternative possibility (telling `cpan` to install to a different location), but I didn’t find it until after already falling back on `sudo`.