# How can I find out which Perl version was available on older Mac OS X versions?

Tags: perl, macos

I want to create Perl scripts that run on older OS X machines as well as on current versions. Is there a list or a resource where I can find out which Perl versions were distributed with older Mac OS X Versions (10.0 to 10.6)?

Comment: See the update about Apple's Perl opensource page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm sure there is some online resource to find this, probably at [Apple Development Connection](http://developer.apple.com/)

However I have three machines to hand which show me that /usr/bin/perl versions are:

- 5.8.6 on 10.4 (Tiger)
- 5.8.8 on 10.5 (Leopard)
- 5.10.0 on 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

In all cases these are thread enabled.

Starting from Snow Leopard, [multiple versions of perl are supported](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/perlmacosx5.10.0.1.html) under the hood and it also comes with Perl 5.8.9 which you can switch to like so:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.perl Version 5.8.9
```

Also note that 5.10.0 on Snow Leopard is 64-bit.  You can switch to 32-bit by using following:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.perl Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
```

/I3az/

**Update**:

A full list of Perl source code that Apple has compiled with Mac OS X can be found on their [Perl opensource page](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/perl/).

Working out what the packaging version numbers mean and how they refer to each version of Mac OS X may take some effort.  However each package does show which Perl was compiled with the options, patches & extra modules Apple applied to it.

See [Perl and Mac OS X versions](http://transfixedbutnotdead.com/2010/02/03/perl-and-mac-os-x-versions/) for my best stab at working all this out.

Comment: great! thanks for your info. they don't update the major numbers with software update don't they?

Comment: Nope and I haven't noticed them making minor version updates (though they may backport security changes?).

Comment: BTW... On a side note (seeing some other related questions you've asked), do not use CPAN installer with the OSX installed Perl (or for any installed/packaged Perl).  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992720/perl-strategy-for-a-new-snow-leopard-user/1992934

Comment: Steve Jobs would never have allowed Perl to be available on OSX. This is clearly faulty information.

Comment: @draegtun: do you know for 10.0 - 10.3 as well?

Comment: Amazingly I still have an old clamshell iBook hanging around running 10.1 (Puma)!  It reports that it has Perl 5.6.0

Comment: And from memory I think 10.3 (Panther) had Perl 5.8.1

Comment: Darn! I came here after searching for a way to see which version of perl exists in various OSX versions, but your website now shows me "Oh no! This blog’s domain transfixedbutnotdead.com expired!"

Comment: @pipe  - Now fixed :)

Comment: I updated this in https://github.com/briandfoy/mac-perl-versions to make it a JSON file